# Live Logging in ASP.NET Core 3.1 selfhosting-webserver as windows service

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, asp.net-core-3.1

I used to use dbgview to live logging my applications in .NET FW 4. But I'm new to ASP.NET Core, so i'm not able to get it running. When starting the Console-App I get all the output i configured. But how to get this output when installed as windows service. There is no console window available. DbgView does not receive anything...

I added a EventLog, but i want to see more specific and LIVE output in a seperate window like console, dbgview or something like this. Is it possible?

Comment: DbgView isn't meant for logging, it's meant to show *debug* messages sent to a *debugger*. Even in .NET Framework you had to either use TraceListeners or logging libraries like log4net, NLog, Serilog etc.

Comment: Questions about 'what tool should I use for..' are typically closed by StackOverflow. Just find a logging framework of your choice and see what kind of log-viewers it provides. This is a good introduction https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right it's debugging not logging. But when using AddDebug() the Debug.Writeline outputs are going to "direct window" but not to dbgview. What i have to do, to see those outputs there?